# How to get a UIView to show the navigation bar of it's navigationcontroller while in Interface Builder

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4, uinavigationcontroller, interface-builder

I have a UINavigationController, I've added an a UIViewController under the nav controller.

The basic functionality is working fine, I'm able to click an item in my view controller and it takes me to a second view and I can use the back button to go back.

My question is, when I'm in IB, is there a way when I'm editing a VC that is going to be under a NavController to tell the VC "hey, pretend there is a nav bar at the top so that I can lay this view out with that nav bar in mind"? When I open up the xib file for the VC that is going to be under the Nav it shows me a full view to edit, and then when it gets loaded in it shrinks and shifts things and everything is good. But I may want a specific view that fits a certain way on the screen, and having the title bar up top would be nice as a reference when building a view that is going to be used under a nav controller.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select the main `UIView` in IB. In the properties, go to the Attributes Inspector. You'll see "Simulated Metrics". There is a pulldown for Top Bar. Set it to Navigation Bar.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. Was looking for something like that, but must have overlooked the "Simulated Metrics" section.

Comment: I have a really similar problem. Just that when I load my xib and the controller later on gets pushed onto a navigation controller, I don't see any of the changes that I'd made to the navigation bar in the xib. Any suggestions?